# Linq with HashTable Matching

Tags: regex, vb.net, linq

I need another pair of eyes.  I've been playing around with this LINQ syntax for scanning a Hashtable with a regular express.  Can't seem to get it quite right.  The goal is to match all keys to a regular expression, then using those results match the remaining values to an separate regular expression.  In the test case below, I should end up with the first three entries.

```
Private ReadOnly Property Testhash As Hashtable
    Get
        Testhash = New Hashtable
        Testhash.Add("a1a", "abc")
        Testhash.Add("a2a", "aac")
        Testhash.Add("a3a", "acc")
        Testhash.Add("a4a", "ade")
        Testhash.Add("a1b", "abc")
        Testhash.Add("a2b", "aac")
        Testhash.Add("a3b", "acc")
        Testhash.Add("a4b", "ade")
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub TestHashSearch()

    Dim KeyPattern As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("a.a")
    Dim ValuePattern As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("a.c")

    Try
        Dim queryMatchingPairs = (From item In Testhash
                                  Let MatchedKeys = KeyPattern.Matches(item.key)
                                  From key In MatchedKeys
                                  Let MatchedValues = ValuePattern.Matches(key.value)
                                  From val In MatchedValues
                                  Select item).ToList.Distinct

        Dim info = queryMatchingPairs

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you match both the key and value at the same time?

```
Dim queryMatchingPairs = (From item In Testhash
                          Where KeyPattern.IsMatch(item.Key) And ValuePattern.IsMatch(item.Value) 
                          Select item).ToList
```

Comment: Definitely more elegant!

Answer (score 0):

I should have taken a break sooner, then worked a little more.  The correct solution uses the original "from item" and not the lower "from key" in the second regular expression.  Also, "distinct" is unnecessary for a hashtable.

```
            Dim queryMatchingPairs = (From item In Testhash
                                      Let MatchedKeys = KeyPattern.Matches(item.key)
                                      From key In MatchedKeys
                                      Let MatchedValues = ValuePattern.Matches(item.value)
                                      From val In MatchedValues
                                      Select item).ToList
```